# attr_accessor not updating value from rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor, attr-accessible

I have the following model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :incentive
end
```

I want to be able to store a temporary column in my model via attr_accessor.

I want to be able to do something like this

```
job = Job.last
job.incentive = {id: 1}
```

and i expect if i do `job.incentive`, it should return `{id: 1}`

I also tried doing this as well

```
def incentive =(val)
  @incentive = val
end

def incentive
  @incentive
end
```

But that also didn't work. How can i be able to store temporary column values in rails 4

Comment: `attr_accessor :incentive` should work. What does `job.incentive` return after setting it to some value?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan it returns nil

Comment: Weird. I'm unable to reproduce this issue in a rails 4 app. Do you have a repo to reproduce it?

Comment: if it is temporary variable you cannot store to the database, it exists in your model instances only, i supposed

Comment: Is `incentive` a database column name? Do you expect the value to end up in the database? What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: no incentive is not a database column. And no i don't expect the value to end up in the database. I just need it to be accessible temporary @spickermann

Answer (score 1):

You script is fine, you'll find the below script working perfectly in your rails console:

```
job = Job.last
job.incentive = { id: 1 }
p job.incentive # returns { id: 1 }
```

If you restart or refresh your console (or webpage) this information is gone, since it is only set in memory and not stored to the database.